# Necessary condition for convergence of a multi-dimensional series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am solving an economic system, (can be visualized as a state space model.)
There is a state process $\{Y_t\}$ and a price process $\{P_t\}$. The solution for $\{P_t\}$ is given by:

\begin{align*}
P_t = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\exp \bigg(\underbrace{B_n^T}_{1 \times 3} \underbrace{{Y_t}}_{3 \times 1}\bigg)
\end{align*}
Here $Y_t$ is a $3\times 1$ vector and $B_n$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix. $P_t$ is a scalar. The solution for the sequence $B_n$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{B_n^T}_{1 \times 3} = \underbrace{B_{n-1}^T}_{1 \times 3} \underbrace{A}_{3 \times 3} + \underbrace{K}_{1 \times 3}
\end{align*}
with $B_1 = [0,0,0]^T$.
I want to find a necessary condition for finiteness of $P_t$. Here is what I have so far. $P_t$ can be seen as a series, with each term $\exp(B_n^T Y_t)$. One necessary condidtion is:
\begin{align*}
 \exp(B_n^T Y_t) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align*}
This can happen if $B_n^T Y_t \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. We can assume for simplicity $Y_t > 0$. So I need a necessary condition for $B_n \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Can we find such a necessary condition for multi-dimensional series ? I am guessing it might have to do with eigenvalues of $A$, but I am not sure.